# How to unzip and parse multiple files in Scrapy

Tags: python, pandas, scrapy

I am trying to parse a list of .txt files within a zip folder but it's only parsing one file from that list

**Code:**

```
    def custom_parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info(response.url)
        links = response.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '.zip')]/@href").getall()
        for link in list(set(links)):
            print(link)
            local_path = self.download_file("https://www.sec.gov" + link)
            zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(local_path)
            zip_csv_files = [file_name for file_name in zip_file.namelist() if file_name.endswith(".txt") and "pre" not in file_name]
            zip_csv_file = zip_csv_files[0]
            with zip_file.open(zip_csv_file, "r") as zip:
                # df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(zip.read()), dtype=object)
                df = pd.read_csv(zip, dtype=object, header=None, sep='delimiter')
            df = self.standardized(df)
            for k, row in df.iterrows():
                yield dict(row) 

    def standardized(self, df):
        # df.columns = [col.lower().strip().replace(" ", "_") for col in df.columns]
        df = df.fillna('')
        return df
```

I am going to assume it's due to `zip_csv_file = zip_csv_files[0]` but I am unsure how I can modify my current code to parse all the .txt files in a given zip folder.

Answer (score 0):

You already pull out all the .txt files with your list comprehension, so just read those in a loop and concatenate them. This is untested, but should be close

replace the appropriate section of your code with this:

**UPDATE:**

```
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(local_path)
text_files = zip_file.infolist()
df_list =[]
for file_name in text_files:
    if file_name.filename.endswith(".txt") and "pre" not in file_name.filename:
        df_list.append(pd.read_csv(zip_file(open(file_name.filename)), dtype=object, header=None, sep='delimiter'))
df = pd.concat(df_list)
df = self.standardized(df)
```

Comment: I am getting a FileNotFoundError: [Erno 2] No such file or directory: 'sub.txt' after implementing that code. 'sub.txt' was the first file that was being parsed in my previous code.

Comment: Right, b/c it’s not extracted. You can break apart the list comprehension and use that loop instead. There are a few examples on SO to show this but I can look later to see if I can find them.

Comment: If you can provide me with an example that will be great. Thanks for the help!

Comment: updated the answer with an adapted version of what I used in the past. give that a try.

Comment: Hi Jon, I'm getting a "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'filename'". Did you mean zipfile(open(file_name))? It also appears the compiler is throwing an error using infolist(): AttributeError: 'ZipInfo' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Comment: if file_name.endswith(".txt") and "pre" not in file_name might need to be if file_name.filename.endswith(".txt") and "pre" not in file_name.filename but i'm using infolist() just as it's written so not sure what is going as i can't test with your local path or csv files.